# Error occured while doing automation testing with Ranorex tool. Please suggest me that how could I solve these type of cases in automation

Tags: authentication, automated-tests, functional-testing

This time i have recorded a Test script using **Ranorex tool** for the login functionality. and this time login is done and after that when clicking on the menu bar the error displayed as **"No element found for path 'dom[4]/.//span[#'aui_3_4_0_1_637']' within 1m.
Failed to find item 'sekar1Repository.WelcomeSaarccasesCom.Aui3401637'"**.

Actually, I have recorded using **Ranorex tool** script for login functionality. In my recorded script, I have performed an operation "click" for "login" and then entering the user name and password, after that the home page is open with menu bar with multiple tasks. in that i click on first functionality and then proceeding the further steps and after that i play the entire script. this time login made sucessfully but at the time of clicking tab menu the error message thrown as **"No element found for path 'dom[4]/.//span[#'aui_3_4_0_1_637']' within 1m.
Failed to find item 'sekar1Repository.WelcomeSaarccasesCom.Aui3401637'"** and the case ends with failiure.

Please suggest me that how could I solve these type of cases. Because every time when I run that recorded script it will show the same error message and discontinue the script.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

When you record a test case, it can happen (with all the tools). 
I think that the html span got an id generate by the site, changing each time. I encourage you to use a css class or other information to get the span.

Something like : 
dom[4]/.//span[@name=login]

Fabrice